# Getting last updated forum topic even if it has not been posted on

Tags: mysql

I am writing a simple forum script for a club to post on and I am having a brain fart :)  Trying to be simple, I have 2 tables :

forum - id, title, description, display_order

posts - id, title, content, thedate(DATETIME), mid(Member ID), forum_id, of_id

The "of_id" is for posts that are "comments" on a certain post.  This means of_id will equal the original posts "id".  The first post will have an "of_id" of 0.

What I am trying to do is retrieve the id and title of last few "threads" that were either just created or recently posted in.  Hopefully that makes sense!

EDIT********  Added SQL FIDDLE test

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/185fb)

The end result should be the result below :

Test 2
Test Post
Empty thread

Comment: Can you please tell where the of_id comes from is it equal to posts-id in the first post. Please provide more information on table structure

Comment: The best way I can explain it is and example :  If I post in the forum, it creates a row in the table "posts".  The ID is an auto increment so lets say the ID = 1.  Since it is the first post, of_id = 0 since I am not posting one someone else post.  If someone posts on my post, the auto increment value would be 2, but the of_id will equal 1 since they are posting on my post.

Comment: do you want latest posts of specific forum or post id or everything posted recently and also how recent such as past one hour or so ?

Comment: I am wanting to display the last 10 or so "threads" that have been created or posted on.  The of_id that equals "0" is a new thread.  If the of_id equals anything other than 0, it is a comment on a "thread" and the of_id equals the ID of the original post.  What i want to display is the title of the original thread.  I can't use "GROUP BY" since the of_id of the first post will always equal 0.

Comment: Instead of using words to describe the data and wanted outcome, supply some sample data and the expected result from that sample data, also provide the DDL of the table(s); &/or you could setup your own sqlfiddle. Don't rely on us to provide the sample

Comment: post your example data and the output you want

Comment: Did the SQLFIDDLE link work?  That has the example data and under the link, I added the example output which is the title of each result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer tested on your fiddle and will return the desired output :

```
select original.title,original.of_id,
CASE 
    WHEN  comment.thedate is null THEN original.thedate
    ELSE comment.thedate
END as postedDate
FROM posts as original
LEFT join posts as comment ON (comment.of_id=original.id)
WHERE original.of_id=0
ORDER BY postedDate DESC
```

Comment: That is perfect!  Thank you very much for the help.  Sorry for the confusion!  I did not know about SQLFIDDLE until about an hour ago :)

Comment: no worries good to know it helped ..posting the input data and the sample output really helps others in solving the problem

Comment: I hate to bring this alive again, but I just ran into another issue with this same code.... If there are more than 1 comments posted under the same post, the query above returns the original post multiple times.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Just figured it out on my own :)  Needed to use GROUP BY of_id, id